# How to detect if database has changed directories in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am using Access to maintain both the frontend and backend databases and as such the FE is linked to BE tables.

I need to detect if the FE file has changed directories in order to prompt user to change table links (For backup/dev/testing purposes) to ensure the live data won't be modified.

Is there a way to detect this in Access through VBA?

This is part 1 of creating a utility feature that allows users to automatically change table links when the system detects the path of the file has been changed.

Comment: Not sure to understand: you say you want to detect if the FE changed directories. Directories of what? The FE itself? Then you don't need to relink your BE tables. If its not that please detail

Comment: Currently we are using Access '07, and everytime you copy the FE file the table links is kept with to the original live backend database. We don't want that, therefore I want to detect change in directory to prompt user if they want to relink tables to their "dev" copies of the backend. Hope this is more clear. @ThomasG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little function returns the path for the current DB - will that help?

```
Function WhereAmI() As String
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFile(CurrentDb().Name)
share = f.Drive.ShareName
If Len(share) = 0 Then
    share = CurrentDb().Name
    Else: share = share & Mid(CurrentDb().Name, 3)
    End If
WhereAmI = share
End Function
```

Comment: The `CurrentProject.Path` property shows the path of the folder where the current db is located.  `CurrentProject.FullName` or `CurrentDb.Name` give you the full path including the db file name.

Comment: If the path already changed, how would I be able to compare the paths? @Don
Is there a way of storing this value and alllow it to be accessed across multiple users?

Comment: @Jabberbyter - You can make a table in the database and use it to store where you think the DB is, and then compare its actual location to the stored location.  If they match, you're fine.  If not, your user will need to relink the tables, and update the location stored in the new table.

Comment: @HansUp - They don't work for me because they give they use the local mapping of a network drive - ie, "f:\" in the file name.  Other users may have their network drives mapped differently, so my f:\ may be their g:\ drive.  My function converts that to a URL that doesn't rely on the drive mapping - ie "\\server\" instead of "f:\"

Answer (score 0):

I addition to my other answer, I have the following code that remaps all linked tables in a DB.  In  my case, I have a table with 2 rows to show the source tables I need to link to if my current db is local (on my C:\ drive) or on a network drive.  If I want to map the links to a network drive, the location in my table is the URL - ie, "\\server\file" so any user can get to it without relying on  how they have their network drives mapped.

I usually put this in an AutoExec macro to automatically link to the correct source when I open the data base.  It also remaps the library with my common code modules at the same time.

This also simplifies relinking tables when I have to roll over to the new year - just change the source file in  the table and all the linked tables update to refer to the new year's source data.

```
Function relink_tables()

If Left(CurrentDb().Name, 2) = "C:" Then
    Source = "local"
    Else: Source = "network"
    End If
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from [linked table source] where source='" & Source & "'")
Source = rs.Fields("path")

For Each R In References
    If InStr(R.Name, "Common Tables") > 0 Then Application.References.Remove R
    Next R
Application.References.AddFromFile Source

x = 0
Set TDefs = CurrentDb().TableDefs
For Each table In TDefs
    If InStr(table.Connect, "Common Tables") = 0 Then GoTo NT
    table.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & Source
    table.RefreshLink
    x = x + 1
NT:
    Next table
Finish:
MsgBox "remapped " & x & " tables"
End Function
```